# how to load data into a tree store .the data coming from a reader of another tree store

Tags: extjs4

I have couple of tree panels, each configured with individual tree stores. I have configured a proxy for one store. On load event of this, i am trying to load the second store(proxy memory) like below. But it doesn't work.

EXT js Version: 4.0.7

```
_treeStore2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'Scenario',
    proxy   : {
         type    : 'memory'         
    }

});

_treeStore1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'Scenario',     
    root:'data1',
    proxy   : {
         type    : 'ajax',
         url: '/proj/examples?id='+_Id,          
         reader  : {
             type    : 'json',
             root:'data1'
            }
    },
    listeners: {
         'load': {
              fn: function(store, records, success, operations) {           
                              _treeStore2.setRootNode(_treeStore1.getProxy().getReader().jsonData.data2);           
                                 } 
    }
});
```

Sample JSON data:

```
{"data1":[{"name":"value","children":[]}],"data2":[{"name":"value","children":[]}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using loadData(data2) or loadRawData methods.
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadRawData

Comment: Thanks dbrin

I tried this but didn't worked out saying loadRawData() is not a function in TreeStore.